# Excel count of distinct IDs

Tags: excel

Does anyone know the formula for counting distinct values in Excel cells?
I know it can be done with pivots but I need to get it via a formula and it must be done without Remove duplicates or Advanced filter method (no data must be copied to new columns, etc).

The data looks like this:

```
Continent | ID
Asia      | 10
Asia      | 10
Asia      | 11
Asia      | 14
Europe    | 100
Europe    | 100
```

So a distinct count of Asia = 3 and Europe = 1.

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed. This should get you started: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=excel+formula+count+unique

Answer (score 2):

If the IDs are **numbers** you can use this formula

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A$2:A$10="Asia",B$2:B$10),B$2:B$10),1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

For **any** data type this version will work

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A$2:A$10="Asia",IF(B$2:B$10<>"",MATCH(B$2:B$10,B$2:B$10,0))),ROW(B$2:B$10)-ROW(B$2)+1),1))`

Comment: this gives me a result of 1 instead of 3 for Asia.

Comment: Which formula? Make sure you use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. If done correctly you see curly braces like { and } around the formula

Answer (score 0):

count.if should do for you: you have to set the interval to the column where the countries are and criteria to 'ASIA' i.e.

Comment: countif(concatenate(continent + id)) should help

Comment: countif counts how many times ASIA10 is repeated in the table. That is what he is asking, no?

Comment: yeah, you are right... then should be usefull some vba i fear